# Kinematics problem solving (constant acceleration)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A falling stone takes 0.33s to travel past a window 2.2m tall. From what height above the top of the window did the stone fall?

My workings are as follows: I calculated the velocity of the falling stone $\frac {2.2}{0.33}$, I then used $v = v_o + at$ where $a= -9.8m/s^2$ to find the time it takes for the stone to reach that velocity calculated at the start. where did I go wrong or how do I continue the problem?

Comment: The stone is accelerating. That's your hint.

Comment: common misconception: Velocity is not equal to displacement/time. (That's average velocity. It is equal when the velocity is constant.)

Answer (score 1):

By the kinematics equation $$S=\frac{1}{2}\cdot g t^{2} + v_0 \cdot t$$, where $v_0$ is the velocity of the stone before it reaches the window, S is the vertical distance covered($2.2m$) in that time interval of $t = 0.33s$

Isolating for $v_0$, $$v_0 = \frac {S- \frac {1}{2}gt^{2}}{t}$$
This gives you the velocity at which the stone entered the area of the window. Using $v^{2}=2gh$, solve for $h$ and you get roughly $1.3m$

Answer (score 0):

Orientate the axis downward so g=9.8 m/s^2
Use:  $$ \triangle x= V_{0}  \triangle t+ \frac{1}{2}g \triangle t^{2}$$
$$ \triangle x=2.2 m$$
$$\triangle t=0.33 s$$
Solve for $V_{0}$